# JQuery UI Autocomplete in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

```
    I have implemented Jquery UI Autocomplete functionlaity in Liferay 6 ...
```

its running well but when I'm dng this into Liferay 5.2.3 .....its having various probelms with Jquery .....Can I use js 1.4 version files in my custom portlet????...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Liferay older versions use JQuery which may be conflicting with your version of JQuery library. Liferay 6 has resolved that issue by introducing AlloyUI which uses YUI library. Liferay 6 does not contain any Jquery library in it so any version you use should go well.

I can think of two ways to solve this problem

- On liferay 5 do not add your own JQuery library. just add the plugin js and see if it works.
- You check the JQuery version which ships with Liferay 5.2.3 and see if your autocomplete plugin works with it.

Hope this helps